# How to get sum of an attribute value which is referenced by id multiple times with xpath in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I really do hope that my title is at least a bit clear.

**important: i can only use xslt 1.0 because the project needs to work with the MSXML XSLT processor.**

What I try to do:
I generate documents containing information about rooms. Rooms have walls, I need the sum of wall area of these per room.

The input xml file I get is dynamically created by another program.
Changing the structure of the input xml file is not the solution, trust me, it's needed like that and is much more complex than I show you here.

My XML (the innerArea attribute in the wall element has to get summed up):

```
<root>
    <floor id="30" name="EG">
        <flat name="Wohnung" nr="1">
            <Room id="49" area="93.08565">
                <WallSegments>
                    <WallSegment id="45"/>
                    <WallSegment id="42"/>
                    <WallSegment id="39"/>
                </WallSegments>
            </Room>
        </flat>
    </floor>
    <components>
        <Wall id="20" innerArea="20.7654"/>
        <wallSegment id="45" wall="20">[...]</wallSegment>
        <Wall id="21" innerArea="12.45678"/>
        <wallSegment id="42" wall="21">[...]</wallSegment>
        <Wall id="22" innerArea="17.8643"/>
        <wallSegment id="39" wall="22">[...]</wallSegment>
    </components>
</root>
```

With my XSLT I was able to reach the values of the walls which belong to a room.
But I have really no idea how I could get the sum of the value out of that.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="flat/Room">
    <xsl:for-each select="WallSegments/WallSegment">
        <xsl:variable name="curWallSegId" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/components/wallSegment[@id = $curWallSegId]">
            <xsl:variable name="curWallId" select="@wall"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/components/Wall[@id = $curWallId]">
                <!--I didn't expect that this was working, but at least I tried :D-->
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(@AreaInner)"/> 
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Desired Output should be something like...

```
[...]
<paragraph>
    Room 1:
      Wall area: 51.09 m²
    [...]
</paragraph>
[...]
```

So I hope I described my problem properly. If not: I am sorry, you may beat me right into the face x)

Comment: Why do all your wall segment components have the same id? -- Note also that your input is not well formed - the wall component elements are not closed.

Comment: Just a combination of typo and copypasto ;-) but thanks for telling me.
My original data has unique ids and is well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use **keys** to get "related" data. Place this at the top of your stylesheet, outside of any template:

```
<xsl:key name="wall" match="components/Wall" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="wallSegment" match="components/wallSegment" use="@id" />
```

Then:

```
<xsl:for-each select="flat/Room">
    <paragraph>
        <xsl:text>Room </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>:&#10;  Wall area: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('wall', key('wallSegment', WallSegments/WallSegment/@id)/@wall)/@innerArea), '0.00m²')"/>
        <xsl:text> &#10;</xsl:text>
    </paragraph>
</xsl:for-each>
```

will return:

```
<paragraph>Room 1:
  Wall area: 51.09m²</paragraph>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow.
What is the advantage in using keys for that kind of task?

Comment: Ok, that worked well for me.
Thank you both for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

If what you need it's the area of every room, this is a way of getting it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/root/floor">
        <xsl:for-each select="flat/Room">
            <xsl:variable name="currentRoomSegmentsIds" select="WallSegments/WallSegment/@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="currentRoomWallsIds" select="/root/components/wallSegment[@id = $currentRoomSegmentsIds]/@wall"/>
            <xsl:variable name="currentRoomWallsInnerAreas" select="/root/components/Wall[@id = $currentRoomWallsIds]/@innerArea"/>
            Id of the room = <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>.
            Area of the room = <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentRoomWallsInnerAreas)"/>
        </xsl:for-each> <!-- Enf of for each room -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following result:

`Id of the room = 49.
Area of the room = 51.08648`

Comment: this solution works quite well.
But the last nodeset has double entries for every entry.. maybe it's visual studio's debugger.

Comment: With the XML you have provided in your example, the first variable holds 3 values (45, 42, 39), the second variable holds 3 values (20, 21, 22), and the third variable holds 3 values too (20.7654, 12.45678, 17.8643). With another examples the first two variables could have duplicated values, but the third variable will only have innerAreas of different walls as long as /root/components doesn't have two Wall with the same id.